# How do I bulk change the folder hierachy of files?

Tags: database, data-structures, renaming

I have the following paths currently:

E:\Testing\mp3_part1\ **x**\ **y**\filename.mp3

There are 200 'x' folders and 5 'y' folders. Contained within each y folder are 1-1000 files

For all the end files I need to change the pathname to:

E:\Testing\ **y**\ **x**\filename.mp3

I feel like there is a simple, and quicker way to do this than a bunch of copy/pasting. Help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what language you're writing in, but most runtime libraries have a "move" function that will do the copy. They also have functions that will get a list of files from a folder.

The basic idea, then is:

```
for x in xValues
    for y in yValues
        sourceDir = "E:\Testing\mp3_part1\" + x + "\" + y + "\"
        destDir = "E:\Testing\" + y + "\" + x + "\"
        sourceFiles = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.mp3")
        for each file in sourceFiles
            File.Move(file, destDir + file.name)
```

You'll need to change `Directory.GetFiles` and `File.Move` to reflect whatever runtime library you're using. I got those names from the .NET runtime, although it's possible I got the parameters wrong.

The nice thing about the `File.Move` functionality is that it can move the file by just changing the directory entry, rather than having to actually copy the bits from one location to another, and then delete the old file. This can go very quickly if the source and destination are on the same logical drive.